# How do I hide the Windows 7 start button

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to hide the Windows 7 start button?

I can hide the entire taskbar, but the start button is still visible.

The name of its exe is winlogon.exe in Task Manager.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you want to cover the screen, just create a fullscreen window and the taskbar and Start button will autohide.

Answer (score 0):

You might find how to disable Start menu [here](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/completely-disable-start-menu-376790.html)